# Firebase Authentication(Goggle) in Angular

Tags: angularjs, firebase-authentication, angularfire2

I'm working on firebase authentication, getting this error:

> Property 'auth' does not exist on type 'AngularFireAuth'.

```
return this.afAuth.auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
      .then((result) => {
        this.ngZone.run(() => {
          this.router.navigate(['dashboard']);
```

getting error on `auth`

Answer (score 0):

@Abdullah, `auth` is not a part of `AngularFireAuth`, it is a part of `firebase` package.

Update your code as below

```
import * as firebase from 'firebase/app';
```

*npm install firebase --save dependency if not installed*

```
return firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
      .then((result) => {
        this.ngZone.run(() => {
          this.router.navigate(['dashboard']);
```

Comment: I have tried this one but still not working, I have updated the code but still getting the error  code return this.afAuth.firebase.auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)

Answer (score 0):

I was working with the same project I think. I found that from "@angular/fire": "^6.0.0" AngularFireAuth has dropped the auth property.

Use this code instead:

```
this.afAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
```

Source: https://github.com/angular/angularfire/issues/2409#issuecomment-615993136

Comment: The last part of your post does not provide an answer to the question. It asks a follow up question. You can [search for similar questions](//stackoverflow.com/search), or refer to the related and linked questions on the right-hand side of the page to find an answer. If you have a related but different question, [ask a new question](//stackoverflow.com/questions/ask), and include a link to this one to help provide context. See: [Ask questions, get answers, no distractions](//stackoverflow.com/tour)